# In generally, is it a bad sign to store different types in a list?

Tags: php, oop, generics, polymorphism

So lets given a list:

```
class A
{
    public function methodA() { }
}

class B
{
    public function methodB() { }
}

$list = [];
$list[] = new A();
$list[] = new A();
$list[] = new B();
```

or with common typed:

```
abstract class C
{
    public function methodC() { }
}

class A extends C
{
    public function methodA() { }
}

class B extends C
{
    public function methodB() { }
}

$list = [];
// at least $list elements are instanceof C
$list[] = new A();
$list[] = new A();
$list[] = new B();
```

the main problem is whenever I want to use `methodB()`, I have to make sure its `B` based. It all could applies to Java: we should constantly cast / use gerenics.
I know the classic array stores elements with the same type. Does it applies to list?

Or to turn it around: should I store `A`-s and `B`-s in separated containers?

Comment: Please choose one language.

Comment: You should take advantage of polymorphism, where `method()` is defined abstractly in `C` and implemented via subtypes. You could interact with different types of objects (`A`, `B`) using the same interface (`C`).

Comment: @Eran ok, I chose Php, but it applies to Pascal, C, Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the specifics of different languages for a minute, and focusing on the main issue here.

#### General Practice

Whenever you declare a new variable (in a block or also as a method's parameter) you should always consider declaring its *static type* to be the most generic one that fits your needs.
This helps make the code much cleaner, since the reader (which can also be yourself, later in the future) will know what you meant when you wrote the code.
Furthermore, this practice encourages, without giving it too much thought, the practice of [low coupling and high cohesion](https://thebojan.ninja/2015/04/08/high-cohesion-loose-coupling/) since it encourages the "user" class to know as little as possible about the "product" class. And of course, it also motivates the use of interfaces, inheritance etc.

#### Your Example

To make the explanation more intuitive, I'll give meaning to the different classes.

Let us assume that class `C` is "food". `A` is "Apple" and `B` is "Burger".

Now, if we want to have a collection of *food* items, we should create a collection of `C`. For example, to list all of the items ordered in a restaurant.
This lets us use features known to all "food" items, for example, "getCalories()". So, when the meal is over, we can iterate that collection of `C` (Food) items, and simply invoke (and aggregate) `some_c_object.getCalories()`.

On the other hand, if we want to use a specific attribute (or behavior) of `A` itmes (Apples), we would want to use a collection of apples. For example, let's assume that the class implements the method `hasWorms()`. This lets us verify that that no *Apple* in our collection has a worm in it. This is clearly irrelevant for *Burgers* ( hopefully ;) ).

#### How does this motivates better practice?

To connect both of my previous points: Imagine now that you want to iterate all of you order, that is a generic collection of `Food`. But, because you know that an `Apple` might have worms in it, you want to verify that the ones in the order do not have those. You might be tempted to simply iterate the cart, ask `if current_item is Apple` and if it is, cast this `current_item` to an `Apple` and check `HasWorms()`. If it has any, cancel the order.

But, this could (and in most cases should) trigger you to think a little harder. Maybe you should verify that every item is OK? For example, that the Burger's meat color is regular. Now you can consider to approach this in a few manner, but I'll use the classes we already have for simplicity (not adding any new interface or such). You can add `isValid()` method to `Food` class (this can be abstract, for example). The `Apple` class would just return `HasWorms()` and the `Burger` class would return `True` if the color is in the right range. Then, when the order is done, you can simply call `isValid()` of every `Food` item.

### Conclusion

This is a very simple example, based on the one you specified in your question. I hope it helps solves you dilemma, and I strongly suggest you read more about OOP Polymorphism best practices online. There are a lot of great sources such as [this one](http://liemur.com/software-development-best-practices-polymorphism/).